# Check if integer in 3rd position is 5

Tags: c#, exception, integer

I am trying to come up with an expression that checks for given integer if its third digit from right-to-left is 5.
What I managed so far is this:

```
string input = "5";

if (Regex.IsMatch(input[2].ToString(), "[5]"))
{
    System.Console.WriteLine("yes");
}
else
    System.Console.WriteLine("no");
```

Got 2 problems with this:

First it counts from left to the right not from right to the left and 
second when the number is less than 3 digits like in this case return out of range exception.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a numerical way. If the number is greater than 99 and `n` is your integer then use

```
(n / 100) % 10 == 5
```

`n / 100` removes the last two digits (integer division truncates) and the `% 10` extracts the now rightmost digit. Check if it's 5 or not.

It will be much faster than using a regular expression.

Comment: doesn't work with: _I am trying to come up with an expression that checks for given integer if its third digit from **right-to-left** is 5._

Answer (score 1):

Bathsheba's answer is much better, but if you would like to use a regular expression, I believe this one will fit your needs: `^\d+(?:[5](\d){2})$`

Answer (score 1):

Refer to @Bathsheba concept,

```
(n % 1000) / 100 == 5
```

can do the same thing.

`(n % 1000)` remains at most 3 digits from right to left

`/100` to take the 3rd digit

Answer (score 0):

Yeah RegEx is not really something I would consider here. Since there is a clever non-conversion answer already I will just give the simplest answer that converts to a string;

```
  if (myInt.ToString().Length >= 3 && myInt.ToString()[2] == '5')
       //it's good
  else
      // it's bad
```

Because compounding expressions short circuit in C# I can have both of those statements in the same if without any fear of getting an `IndexOutOfRangeException`

Answer (score 0):

Since the question was :

> from right-to-left

```
if (myInt.ToString().Length >= 3 && myInt.ToString()[myInt.ToString().Length - 3] == '5')
   //it's good
else
   //it's bad
```

Answer (score 0):

Console.Write("Enter a number: ");

```
            long n = long.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            bool result = false;

            if ((n % 1000) / 100 == 5)
            {
                result = true;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(result);
```